# Backup / Restore of DB on MSSQL 2019 to MSSQL 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a production database running on MSSQL 2019 on a hosted platform.
I am wanting to create a sandbox copy of the db with all of the data in a local MSSQL server running 2014.

Everything I've tried  (backup / restore , generating scripts, export data) has error-ed out.

Does anyone have an easy button I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

The harsh and direct answer would be no, you cannot downgrade.

You said scripting out and exporting data doesn't work, did you try to set the database compatibility mode to 2014. Then script out the database and create it on 2014 server. Then export the data?

Comment: When I try to "save or publish scripts", I get an non helpful "error " during Getting the list of objects from "db_name".

Comment: Which version of SSMS are you using to generate the scripts, and what permissions do you have when connecting?

Answer (score 1):

Right answer - generate script. You can set compatible for SQL Server 2014.

Maybe you skipped it's an option?

You can do it via SSMS:

[image]
[image]

Comment: When I try to open the script file, it gives me a memory warning.  Script file is 6 Gb in size.

Comment: Try to export script via sqlcmd.exe. Execute in command line "sqlcmd < script.sql". Also. I work for a company that develops a sqlbackupandftp utility [link](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/) . You can generate a script through it, and then create a restore job and export the script to the database. There you can also specify the compatibility level. I did not add this option in the answer, as this would be an advertisement. But it’s quite possible what it helps you.

Comment: 6GB, just a curiosity... did you select to script the data long with it?